# Ubuntu, how to start a program without using the terminal

Tags: 14.04, gui, searchmonkey

on Ubuntu 16.04 I installed "searchmonkey" using the command line. I'd rather avoid the command line. How can I start programs from the Ubuntu GUI?

Comment: I think he wants to create a new application desktop shortcut

Answer (score 3):

If you know the executable name, all you have to do is press `Alt + F2`, then type the executable.

Answer (score 2):

On the default desktop, at the top left, there is a icon labelled `Activities`. Click on this and enter the command you want into the `Search` box.

You can right-click on the program once you have located it, to add it to the favourites. It will then be available as an icon on the main navigation bar.

Alternatively, use the `Enter a command` dialogue. The default keyboard shortcut for this is `Alt + F2` -- but this can be adjusted in keyboard settings.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the first icon in the launcher at the top left hand corner of your screen.

Type in the name of the program you wish to launch.

When the program launches, you will see an icon is added to the launcher.

Right click on the icon and select Lock to Launcher.

Then, after closing the program, the option will be present in the launcher.

[A short video showing th basic principles](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgrywzu9m9o78bi/locktolauncher.ogv?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the store (I run an outdated version so I can't really check), you could launch it from there. Worked for me with some apps.